# how can i return a changing int within a string in python?

Tags: python, string, int, return-value

the function i am working on is supposed to tell a user whether a number they have given is a perfect number or not (i.e. is equal to half the sum of its factors). if a user gives the number 8, the output should look like this:

```
8 is not a perfect number
```

but i can't figure out what to put in the return statement to make the int, which changes depending on the user input, print out with the string. the code so far looks like this:

#the code is within another larger function which is the reason for the elif

```
 elif(message == 2):
    num1 = int(input("""Please enter a positive integer :"""))
    while(num1 <= 0):
        print("Number not acceptable")
        num1 = int(input("""Please enter a positive integer :"""))
    thisNum = isPerfect(num1)
    if(thisNum == True):
        return num1, is a perfect number
    elif(thisNum == False):
        return num1 is not a perfect number

def isPerfect(num1):
    sumOfDivisors = 0
    i = 0
    listOfDivisors = getFactors(num1)
    for i in range(0, len(listOfDivisors) - 1):
        sumOfDivisors = sumOfDivisors + listOfDivisors[i]
        i += 1
    if(sumOfDivisors / 2 == num1):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

if i were to do return(num1, "is not a perfect number") it would come out like 
(8, 'is not a perfect number')

Comment: `return '{} is not a perfect number'.format(num1)`

Comment: By the way, your summing operation is wrong.  You are iterating from `0 - len(listOfDivisors) - 1`, but you are incrementing `i` within your loop each time, making i increase by 2 in each pass.  Consider using the `sum` function, like `sumOfDivisors = sum(getFactors(num1))`

Answer (score 1):

convert the integer to a string and concatenate the rest of your statement:

```
return str(num1) + ' is not a perfect number'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return "%d is not a perfect number" % number
```

You can do this with string formating using %s. Anyway there is some other ways as describes [String Formating Operators](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.format()` mini language, and at the same time, simplify your code:

```
 elif(message == 2):
    num1 = int(input("""Please enter a positive integer :"""))
    while(num1 <= 0):
        print("Number not acceptable")
        num1 = int(input("""Please enter a positive integer :"""))
    if isPerfect(num1):
        return '{} is a perfect number'.format(num1)
    else:
        return '{} is not a perfect number'.format(num1)
```

Also in your other method, simply return the result of the comparison:

```
def isPerfect(num1):
    sumOfDivisors = 0
    listOfDivisors = getFactors(num1)
    for i listOfDivisors:
        sumOfDivisors += i
    #if(sumOfDivisors / 2 == num1):
    #    return True
    #else:
    #    return False
    return sumOfDivisors / 2 == num1
```

Also, I would suggest having a read of [PEP-8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which is the style guide for Python.